# Values and index operations between multidimensional numpy arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

(I have no idea how to name that question. So feel free to edit)

I have the following arrays :

- 3D array containing value for [z, y, x]
- 3D array containing altitude for [z, y, x]
- 2D array containing maximum_altitude for [y, x]

z, y, x have the same length for the 3 arrays.

I would like a new 2D output containing value_at_max_altitude for [y, x]

The algorithm should be something like

```
find z where altitude[z, y, x] > max_altitude[y, x]
value_at_max_altitude[y, x] = value[z, y, x]
```

How would you do that with numpy?

**edit:
Here is the solution I have actually. But I was wondering if it is possible to use numpy internal functions to avoid loop:**

```
# get index of Z for first value != False
z = np.argmax(altitude >= max_altitude, axis=0)

# z shape is [x, y]
ny, nx = z.shape

# initialize empty array
value_at_max_altitude = np.empty([ny, nx])

# fill value_at_max_altitude
for y in range(ny):
   for x in range(nx):
     value_at_max_altitude[y, x] = value[z[y, x], y, x]
```

Comment: What about `where altitude[z, y, x] <= max_altitude[y, x]`?

Comment: Just to be clear, does 3D mean it represents data in 3d space, which would be an array with `n` rows and 3 columns?  Or is the array shape a 3 element tuple (a real numpy 3d array)?

Comment: if you can share some data I'll give it a go :)

Comment: 3D array? or Nx3 D array? 2nding @Yuca: this question requires example data

Comment: @kevinkayaks maybe somebody with amazing abstraction capabilities can figure it out, I'm just acknowledging my limitations lol

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, you are trying to do something like the following.  Because you didn't provide example data, I'm not sure, but I think this matches the solution using loops that you already have.

```
import numpy as np

# Generate example data
nz, ny, nx = 7, 5, 3
value = np.random.uniform(size=(nz, ny, nx))
altitude = np.random.uniform(size=(nz, ny, nx))
max_altitude = np.random.uniform(size=(ny, nx))

# Do the indexing
z = np.argmax(altitude >= max_altitude, axis=0)
value_at_max_altitude = value[(z, *np.ogrid[:ny, :nx])]
```

It seems like you are just trying to index into your `value` array with an array `z` of indices.  In that case, you just have to generate arrays with the corresponding `x` and `y` indices which is what I did with [`np.ogrid`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ogrid.html).  The obvious way would be to use `mgrid` but this would generate two arrays of shape `(ny, nx)`.  Using `ogrid` yields arrays of shape `(ny, 1)` and `(1, nx)`, respectively, in this case.  They are still able to index into the array because Numpy [broadcasts](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#purely-integer-array-indexing) during indexing of arrays with arrays.  This is probably only important if you have `nx` and `ny` very large.